# Typescript Higher Order Component as Decorator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I am trying to use Typescript in my React project but am getting stuck at getting the types for my HOC's to function. Here is a minimal example to showcase what I am having trouble with:

```
const withDecorator =
    (Wrapped: React.ComponentType): React.ComponentClass =>
        class withDecorator extends Component {
            render() {
                return <Wrapped {...this.props} />
            }
        }

@withDecorator
class Link extends Component<object, object> {
    render() { return <a href="/">Link</a> }
}
```

This returns the error:

```
'Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
Type 'ComponentClass<{}>' is not assignable to type 'typeof Link'.
    Type 'Component<{}, ComponentState>' is not assignable to type 'Link'.
    Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
        Type '() => string | number | false | Element | Element[] | ReactPortal | null' is not assignable to type '() => Element'.
        Type 'string | number | false | Element | Element[] | ReactPortal | null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
            Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.'
```

I really don't understand why this error occurs. I must be doing something wrong. Things get even more hairy once I introduce props.

I would greatly appreciate the right solution, but I am also very interested in understanding why this error occurs in the first place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class decorator which returns a value is similar to doing

```
const Link = withDecorator(class extends Component<object, object> {
    render() { 
        return <a href="/">Link</a> 
    }
    instanceMethod() { return 2 }
    static classMethod() { return 2 }
})
```

*TypeScript expects the return value of the decorator to have the same type as the input, so the result still has the same behavior.* In your example, the render type signature does not match, but with the added methods the problem is more apparent: with your implementation of the decorator, the following would fail:

```
new Link().instanceMethod()
Link.classMethod()
```

The correct type signature would be:

```
function withDecorator<T extends React.ComponentClass>(Wrapped: T): T
```

and the implementation should match too, most easily by extending the target class:

```
return class extends Wrapped { ... }
```

Note that with React HOC, you don't necessarily want to extend the class, so using a decorator is possibly not the best solution.

See also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9453

Comment: Thank you for your response! I suppose I was thinking of decorators as syntactic sugar for wrapping a class with a function which would allow for the signature of the class to change. I see it's used like that by some libraries, but Typescript has a more conservative opinion of how decorators work.